# Adicionar no código html via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tentando adicionar um código HTML no meu HTML via jQuery,entretando um texto qualquer funciona,já com uma tag do bootstrap não
Por exemplo:

```
$(function($){


$('#enviar').click(function (e) {


    var linhas = $('#linhas').val();
    var plantas = $('#plantas').val();
    var combo=$('#haoum').val();

    var resultado=Number(linhas)+Number(plantas);
    $("#tam").attr("value", resultado);
     if ( combo=="ha" ) {
         $("#divPrincipal").append("Teste");
     }
     else
     {

     }

});
```

Quando rodo o código aparece um teste entre essas tags:

```
<div id="divPrincipal">

            </div>
```

Mas quando eu coloco por exemplo:

```
$(function($){


$('#enviar').click(function (e) {


    var linhas = $('#linhas').val();
    var plantas = $('#plantas').val();
    var combo=$('#haoum').val();

    var resultado=Number(linhas)+Number(plantas);
    $("#tam").attr("value", resultado);
     if ( combo=="ha" ) {
         $("#divPrincipal").append("<p class="text-success">Teste</p>");
     }
     else
     {

     }

});
```

Não funciona,existe alguma outra função sem ser 'append'?

Comment: Seu problema são as aspas duplas dentro de aspas duplas. Isso dá erro (verifique o console do browser). Use aspas simples for fora.

Comment: Desculpe,mas como faz para abrir o console do navegador?

Comment: No Chrome/Windows se não me engano é CTRL+J ou F12

Answer (score 4):

O problema desse trecho do `append` é um erro de sintaxe por causa das aspas duplas aninhadas. Isto:

```
"<p class="text-success">Teste</p>"
```

É interpretado como duas strings com `text-success` no meio:

```
string 1: "<p class="
???:      text-success
string 2: ">Teste</p>"
```

O pedaço do meio é entendido como um identificador (um nome de uma variável, por exemplo), mas na gramática da linguagem não faz sentido um identificador grudado em uma string. No Chrome isso dá o erro de *Unexpected identifier* (ou seja, encontrei um idenficador onde não deveria).

É altamente recomendado abrir o console do browser enquanto você desenvolve. Todos os erros desse tipo serão mostrados lá. Cada browser tem um comando para abrir o console. No Windows, geralmente <kbd>F12</kbd> costuma abri-lo, mas se não funcionar, procure "ferramentas" ou "ferramentas de desenvolvedor" nos menus do seu navegador.

A solução nesse caso é bem, simples, basta usar aspas simples por fora da sua string:

```
$("#divPrincipal").append('<p class="text-success">Teste</p>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Para além do problema que o [@bfavaretto indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41505/129) com as aspas, ie:

```
$("#divPrincipal").append("<p class="text-success">Teste</p>");
```

deve ser:

```
$("#divPrincipal").append('<p class="text-success">Teste</p>');
```

O `.append()` adiciona conteúdo mantendo o conteúdo já existente. Talvez você queira usar o `.html()` que apaga o conteúdo existente e substitui por novo. Ou seja:

```
$("#divPrincipal").html('<p class="text-success">Teste</p>');
```

Caso queira usar o `.append()` invertido, ou seja juntando novo conteúdo antes do conteúdo já existente pode usar `.prepend()`

Answer (score 0):

Adicionalmente a consertar o problema das aspas, você pode criar o objeto de um elemento em *runtime*, adicionar a classe desejada e adicioná-lo à outro:

```
$( '<p/>' ).text( 'Teste' ).addClass( 'text-success' ).appendTo( '#divPrincipal' );
```

A saída, inspecionando o elemento criado:

```
<div id="divPrincipal">
    <p class="text-success">Teste</p>
</div>
```

Caso o texto dentro do parágrafo precise de mais HTML, troque [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) por [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) ou faça mais desse tipo de composição, criando o HTML a ser adicionado à DIV principal e, dentro dele, crie outro objeto, de outro elemento. E por fim, adicione tudo à à DIV.

Eu acho mais complicado, o código fica difícil de ler, mas veja um exemplo:

```js
$( '<p/>' ).text( 'Sucesso' ).addClass( 'text-success' ).prepend(
    
    $( '<span/>' ).addClass( 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' )
    
).appendTo( '#divPrincipal' );
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divPrincipal"></div>
```