# Como faço para apagar valor anterior utilizando javasript

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um selçao de informações, onde no final vai formar o código do produto, conforme a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao escolher os campos ele adiciona, mas se precisar mudar, não apaga o anterior ele permanece é inserido o novo e assim por diante.

**código html**

```
<div>G <p id="teste"></p></div>
```

**código javascript**

```
$(function(){
$("#cidades").change(function(){
            $('#colors div').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
$("#estados").change(function(){
var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"../../paginas/pesquisa/pesquisa_codigo_giga.php?id="+id,
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(res){
            $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();
            $("#cidades").append(res);
        }
    });
});
$("#cidades").change(function(){
var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"../../paginas/pesquisa/pesquisa_codigo_giga_ind_out.php?id="+id,
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(res){
            $("#teste").children(".teste").remove();
            $("#teste").append(res);
        }
    });
});});
```

**código php**

```
<?php
include "../../controle/conexao.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela_indoor_outdoor WHERE tabela_indoor_outdoor_id='$id'";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$nome = $row['tabela_ind_out_cod_giga'];
echo $nome;
}
?>
```

Preciso que ao selecionar os código em sequência ele vai retornando os valores, e se a pessoa alterar, ele apague código antigo e insira o novo.

Comment: Dup? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41497/129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente limpar utilizando a função [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Ao invés de usar `$("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();` use:

```
$("#teste").empty();
```

Desta forma ele irá remover todos os elementos dentro de seu elemento `<p id="teste"></p>`

ou a função [`.text();`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
 $("#teste").text("");
```

Que funciona substituir o texto existente dentro do seu elemento por `""`;

Comment: Obrigado deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Em `cidades` você não precisa atrelar dois eventos `.change`, e depois para substituir os valores basta alterar o método `.append` pelo `.html`:

```
$(function(){
    $("#estados").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"../../paginas/pesquisa/pesquisa_codigo_giga.php?id="+id,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(res){
                $("#cidades").html(res);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#cidades").change(function(){

        $('#colors div').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();

        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"../../paginas/pesquisa/pesquisa_codigo_giga_ind_out.php?id="+id,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(res){
                $("#teste").html(res);
            }
    });
});
});
```